# YII2 API Model Database Connection

Tags: api, yii2

I'm developing a API in YII2 with multiple databases. I want to choose the database in real time. The idea is to read one variable available in controler (API key) to identify the correct connection database in model.

For example in webapplication like a portal i have (it works):

in db default connection i have

```
  'db' => [
            'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
            'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbcompany_0',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ],
```

In model I have

```
public function tableName()
    {
            $schema = '';

            $user = User::find(Yii::app()->user->id);
            $schema = "dbcompany_".  $user->CompanyId;
            return $schema . '.' . 'customer';
    }
```

With this approach I just have a single db connection for all database companies.

How I can apply the same\similiar approach in API. I don't have sessions.

Any idea is well welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new component under db as:

```
 'db1' => [
            'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
            'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbcompany_0',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ],
 'db2' => [
            'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
            'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbcompany_0',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ],
```

And   use it as:

```
Yii::$app->db1 
Yii::$app->db2;
```

Comment: Thanks. I know of that possibility, but what I want is the dbname parameter to be dynamic. Because I have for examples 40 databases. I wouldn't create 40 components and so on. How I can set in controller the correct database connection?

Comment: I think this would give a hint.` Yii::$app->db->dsn = $appConnection->dsn;

Answer (score 0):

All requests are authenticate using a token and this is associated to the user. When the authentication is done YII Framework assigns the userid to \Yii::$app->user->identity->id. So from anywhere I can identify the company owner in model.

```
public static function tableName(){
            $moreinfo= account\Userextra::findOne(\Yii::$app->user->identity->id);
            $schema = \Yii::$app->params['table.prefix'] . $moreinfo->CompanyId;
            return $schema . '.country';
}
```